# Hover CSS only working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, visibility, doctype

Hey, I'm trying to use the CSS hover class and it works fine on Chrome but not on Firefox. Any help appreciated. Here's my CSS:

```
.albumbox .labeltext {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.albumbox:hover .labeltext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And here's the relevant HTML:

```
<a href="http://open.spotify.com/album/2tG6kmDtT5rysmQAtzm5UW" target="_blank"><div class='albumbox'>

<img height="200px" width="200px" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/9351489.jpg" />

<span class='album labeltext'>Escape The Fate<br>Escape The Fate</span>

</div></a>
```

If you want to see the whole page, check it out here http://fyspotify.appspot.com

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most pressing reason is that your page is rendering in [**Quirks Mode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Add this (the HTML5 doctype) as the very first line in the source code, and I'm fairly sure it will automagically work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does automagically fix it, though it's thrown out of position a few other divs and so on. Still, I know how to fix those

Comment: Unless there are other problems, this will also fix the problem in Internet Explorer (where the hover also didn't work).

Comment: No problem. It looks fine to me!

Answer (score 3):

That's because you have block level elements inside inline elements, that is, you have a `<div>` inside an `<a>` and Firefox chooses to render this differently than Chrome as the behaviour is unspecified.

Easiest remedy would be to use a span instead of a div, either way, you cannot have block level elements inside inline elements and expect it to work correctly on all browsers.

Comment: +1. I would add that you can use `inline-block` instead of `block` to get around this problem.

Comment: The easiest fix by far is my answer. Having no doctype is rather silly.

Comment: @thirtydot, adding a doctype doesn't fix the fundamental problem of invalid markup. It's true that it's needed but the markup should be fixed as well.

Comment: The version with the doctype is now live. The markup [doesn't cause (related) errors with HTML5](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffyspotify.appspot.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (can have block elements inside links with HTML5), and it seemingly works in the browsers in this case, so there's no reason to change it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that is because only `<a>` tags have the *`:hover`* event in CSS. Why don't you name that links' class albumbox and set it to *`display:block;`* via CSS?

Result is the same, but will probably be more "conform"!

Comment: This is only true for ancient browsers such as IE6. *(Or IE7/IE8 in Quirks Mode)*.