# CSS :Hover Content Url selector works on Chrome but not on any other browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, hover

I set up this simple hover effect to have a heart image appear over the instagram image when hovering. My client INSISTS on having it. I thought it was all working great because I was on chrome but when checking other browsers it isn't working on anything but chrome. Any advice on what I have wrong would be great. I have read similar articles and tried a few solutions but nothing works.

At the bottom of the page here, hover over the instagram plugin to see the issue: 
http://eddieross.moderndesignmedia.net/

CSS:

```css
.owl-item .box a.swipebox:hover {
content: url("http://eddieross.moderndesignmedia.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/instagram-33.png") !important;
height: 223px;
width: 223px;
z-index: 100;
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: I can't see this style in your file, please say me where this style is situated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question addressing the same issue as you are having. I suggest you check out the first two answers given and maybe they'll work for you.
[Hover CSS only working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390209/hover-css-only-working-in-chrome)

Comment: I did see that post, I tried the <!DOCTYPE html> in the header and it didn't fix anything. I don't really understand the other part but I don't think it applies? I don't have <div> inside of <a>.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this just in case anyone else has the problem.

https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

I added :before to my code and it worked on all browsers. The content: url command apparently only works with :before and :after.

```css
.owl-item .box a.swipebox:hover:before {
 content: url("http://eddieross.moderndesignmedia.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/instagram-33.png") !important;
z-index: 100;
display:inline;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
}
```